# Error creating JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to create a Frame & Panel in Java using swing components but getting error at myframe() that says "invalid declaration, return type required". When my teacher run it in classroom it was successfully run but now its giving error.

```
import javax.swing.*;

class myFrame extends JFrame {

    private mypanel p1;

    myframe() /*here I'm getting error that "invalid decleration, return type required */ {
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setTitle("My First GUI");
        setDeafultCloseOpeartion(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(p1);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class mypanel extends Jpanel {

    private JButton b1;

    mypanel() {
        b1 = new JButton("Click me");
        this.add(b1);
    }
}

class mygui {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        myframe f = new myframe();
        myframe f1 = new myframe();
    }
}
```

Comment: myframe is not the same as myFrame

Comment: ... and the class name should start with an upper case character. That is it should be `MyFrame`.

Comment: extends Jpanel should be JPanel

Comment: I'd argue that it shouldn't even be called MyFrame. That's a rather meaningless name for a component. It should be called something like LoginFrame. It should be entirely descriptive of what it is. I know this is just a test class, but it's worth noting for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your constructor name to myFrame

```
class myFrame extends JFrame {

    //The name of the constructor should be the same as the class name
    myFrame() {
       //...
    }
}
```

And you'd better start your class name with an upper case character like this:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    MyFrame() {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed the constructor name, now its sam like a class name. Its compiling but giving run time error.                                                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptio
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
        at myFrame.<init>(MyGui.java:10)
        at MyGui.main(MyGui.java:27)

Comment: You should change "private MyPanel p1; " to "private MyPanel p1 = new MyPanel();"Because you have to create a instance of MyPanel by keyword new.

Answer (score 3):

You should create object from your panel which is from `mypanel` and add that object in your `JFrame` instead of doing this `private mypanel p1;`

```
import javax.swing.*;

class myFrame extends JFrame {

    // private mypanel p1;

    myFrame() /*here I'm getting error that "invalid decleration, return type required */ {
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setTitle("My First GUI");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mypanel p=new mypanel();
        this.add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class mypanel extends JPanel {

    private JButton b1;

    mypanel() {
        b1 = new JButton("Click me");
        this.add(b1);
    }
}

class mygui {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        myFrame f = new myFrame();
        myFrame f1 = new myFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MyFrame() -> the name of constructor was incorrect